# jQuery-mobile : force jquery mobile initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, web

I'm developing a web site with jquery mobile.
My main page displays a list of items, but I catch those items with an ajax function, and then build HTML document in javascript

The problem is that jQuery Mobile initialize the page before I can modify the page, so the page doesn't look in jqm style.
How can I force jqm to 'rebuild' the page after my modifications ?

Thanks

Comment: I think wich you need execute your ajax function inside a pageshow jMobile event. :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to adjust the DOM before the JQuery Mobile initialization occurs I suggest you do the following:

```
$('#YourPagesId').live('pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  // All of your DOM modification goodness here.
});
```

If you want to modify the DOM after the initial JQuery Mobile initialization has occurred then you would need to fire the appropriate event.

(The examples below are with a list view)

On creation of a new list view do the following:

```
$('#ListViewsId').listview();
```

If you are just modifying an already initialized listview do this:

```
$('#ListViewsId').listview('refresh');
```

More information about the available event like 'pagebeforecreate' can be found here:
[JQuery Mobile Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html)

More informration on how to initialize and refresh a JQuery Mobile Widget can be found here:
[Create vs. refresh: An important distinction](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Comment: ahh thanks ! I was trying with .listView() instead of .listview() -_-